# Maximum inner product of two probability vectors (i.e., vectors with non-negative elements that sum to 1)

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, optimization

Given a vector $\boldsymbol{a} = [a_1 \dots a_n ]^\intercal$ where $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$ and $0\leqslant a_i \leqslant 1$,

I would like to know which vector $\boldsymbol{b}$  maximises the inner product $\boldsymbol{a}^\intercal \boldsymbol{b}$

such that $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i = 1$ and $0\leqslant b_i \leqslant 1$.

$\boldsymbol{a}$ and $\boldsymbol{b}$ are categorical distributions (points on the $n-1$ simplex). Is there an analytic solution here or an intuitive geometric interpretation to the answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $\sum_k a_k b_k \le \max_k a_k$ and if $b=e_k$ then $\sum_k a_k b_k = \max_k a_k$.

Comment: Ah of course. So I guess the inner product $a^\intercal b$ is a convex combination of the elements in $a$, which must be in the range [min$_i a_i$ max$_i a_i$]. In the absence of a proof, is this the right way to think about the inequality you have written? I assume $e_k$ means a one-hot vector with element $k$ taking the 1? Is this standard notation for a one-hot vector (I'm not familiar with it)?

Comment: $e_k$ is standard for the $k$-th vector in the canonical basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is, indeed, exactly what you wrote, @JamesZero: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis

Comment: Well, since $a_k \le \max_k a_k$ we have $\sum_k a_k b_k \le \sum_j b_j \max_k a_k = \max_k a_k$. Yes, $e_k$ is a one hot vector (presumably you have some contact with the digital design world). And yes, the idea that a convex combination is in the $\min,\max$ range is a good way to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

For an interpretation (actually, probabilistic rather than geometric):
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k = \mathbb{P}\{X=Y\}
$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with distributions $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$, respectively. I.e., this is the probability to witness a "collision" between the two samples.

The solution [given by copper.hat](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3617906/75808) then amounts to saying that to maximize the probability of such collisions, $Y$ should be, with probability one, the value that $X$ is the most likely to take.